# How do I grep without whitespaces which between line number and tag?

Tags: regex, sed, grep

```
 grep -in "todo" test.html

 1:            <span>todo:test<span>
```

This will be remove line number and whitespaces:

```
grep -in "todo" test.html | sed -e "s/^[1-9]\d*:[ \t]*//"
```

It will be this:

```
<span>todo:test<span>
```

But I want this:

```
 1:<span>todo:test<span>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this `sed`:

```
sed '/todo/s/^\([1-9]\+:\)[ \t]*/\1/' file.html
```

**Test:**

```
$ echo "1:         <span>todo:test<span>" | sed '/todo/s/^\([1-9]\+:\)[ \t]*/\1/'
1:<span>todo:test<span>
```